# Automated merging of PDF graphs

Tags: pdf, software-rec, document-automation

Is it possible combine PDF graphs automatically? I have similarly named files in 4 different directories. I have been reading about Ghostscript, imageMagick and PDFtk but I am not sure which is the program that would do the job best, as I have no experience with any of them.

This is the case

```
C:\file1\graph1.pdf
C:\file1\graphA-5.pdf
C:\file1\graph2.pdf
C:\file1\graph3.pdf
C:\file1\T-3.pdf
C:\file1\graph4.pdf

C:\file2\256.pdf
C:\file2\graph1.pdf
C:\file2\graph2.pdf
C:\file2\graph3.pdf
C:\file2\graph4.pdf

C:\file3\graph1.pdf
C:\file3\graph2.pdf
C:\file3\graph3.pdf
C:\file3\graph4.pdf

C:\file4\graph1.pdf
C:\file4\graph2.pdf
C:\file4\graph3.pdf
C:\file4\graph4.pdf
```

I would like to combine graph1 from all 4 different directories to look like a 2x2 figure to look like this.

For example:
[image: example]

So the final result would be a new directory, containing PDF images of 2x2 figures, of only graph-1, graph-2, graph-3 and graph-4.

(If you suggest any other programs, I don't mind using any others!)

This question is different from the link that was added above as they are not talking about automated merging there.

Comment: AFAIK pdftk can't do this, although perhaps ImageMagick can.